# Add A CallKit Entry without initiating native UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, user-experience, callkit

I'm having issues with presenting the correct UI when using CallKit.

I would like to be able to create a CallKit call without presenting the native UI (Accept/Reject screen). From my knowledge the only way to create a CallKit object is by using an intent (which still requires the CallKit screen) or present an incoming call screen, which after pressing Accept you have a call going.

I'm using WebRTC as the medium so I can actually "create" calls without CallKit; however when I go to homescreen after initializing calls this way I get a red bar instead of the preferred green bar.

Is there a way around the CallKit screen when creating calls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a behavioral difference between incoming and outgoing calls:

- For *incoming* calls, the system's native incoming call UI (including the Accept and Reject buttons) is always shown, and if the call is answered while the device is unlocked, the user will be taken immediately to the app to continue the call.
- For *outgoing* calls, the system's native call UI is not shown.